# Problem storing HTML text to database field

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store particular text field in database in the html equivalent form.I have used the PHP function

```
$str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

where particular column in database related to `$str` variable has `Column Charset: utf8` & `Column Collate: utf8_bin`. but value is stored in same BLOB form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BLOB` in terms of MySQL is a data type and is different than your character encoding (utf8) or collation. If you want to change the data type, you will have to query your database with...

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY col_name TEXT;
```

or `VARCHAR()` or whatever you want to change it to.

Comment: but `BLOB` is automatically created. I have made `text type` for particular column with the `Column Charset: utf8 & Column Collate: utf8_bin` but while showing this or browsing this its showing like this `[BLOB - 6 B]`.

Comment: That's because your `Column Charset: utf8` and `Column Collate: utf8_bin` assignments aren't correct for what you are trying to do. When you are creating a new table column, you need to query with `ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD col_name TEXT` and your data type will be `TEXT`. The column character set and collation will automatically assign to the the table default.

Answer (score 1):

If you want text in the database, don't use the `BLOB` field type. Use `TEXT`, `VARCHAR`, etc. `BLOB` is for binary data and nothing you do in PHP is going to change the way it's stored in the database.

Comment: BLOB may very well be used for text data as well, but no charset translations will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing large HTML pages, use `LARGETEXT()`